# Losing first line element in file when converting from string to float

Tags: c++, vector, readfile

I have the following problem and I don't know why and how it's happening.

This is my file:

```
###########################
###########################
POINTS
68.252 87.2389 -50.1819
68.2592 87.2451 -50.2132
68.2602 87.2436 -50.2133
68.2564 87.2333 -50.1817
68.2618 87.2475 -50.244
68.2476 87.2446 -50.182
68.2582 87.2466 -50.2131
68.2618 87.2475 -50.244
67.9251 87.2509 -49.8313
67.9311 87.2511 -49.8443
67.9786 87.196 -49.8365
67.9735 87.1946 -49.8231
67.9383 87.2513 -49.8574
67.9848 87.1975 -49.8499
68.0704 87.0819 -49.8067
68.0778 87.09 -49.8349
68.0002 87.2009 -49.8769
68.088 87.1 -49.8633
68.1689 86.9755 -49.8051
68.1709 86.9825 -49.8199
68.1672 86.9693 -49.7903
68.2164 86.9204 -49.7972
68.2157 86.913 -49.7821
...
END
##############################
TRIANGLES
...
```

What I want is to read each line of my file. Split on spaces and convert the string to a float. This is how I am doing it:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;

    ifstream inFile;
    string path = "C:\\...";
    inFile.open(path);

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cerr << "Unable to the open file.";
        exit(1);
    }
```

Basic steps to read my file

```
    int vc_size = numOfPoints(inFile); // A function I implemented to get the number of points

    vector<float> my_coordinates(vc_size);

    int current_pos = 0;
```

Initializing some variables

```
    while (getline(inFile, line))
    {
        if (line == "POINTS")
        {
            while (getline(inFile, line, ' '))
            {
                if (line == "END" || current_pos >= vc_size)
                    break;

                my_coordinates[current_pos] = atof(line.c_str());

                current_pos++;
            }
        }
    }

    inFile.close();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vc_size; ++i)
        cout << my_coordinates[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Even though this seem logical, I have a huge problem. 
The first value of all my lines (except the first one) disappears (meaning all the `68.something` are not in my output). 
And what is more confusing is that if I make my `vector` a `vector<string>` and do `x_coordinates[current_pos] = line;` then the code works. 
This makes no sens to me because the only step that changes is the conversion from `string` to `float` (I tried to convert using `stringstream` but it's the same incorrect result).

Comment: `string path = "C:\\..."; inFile.open(path);` as this can never work, presumably this is not real code.

Comment: I edited it to not let everyone see what path I'm using. It's not an important detail you can omit it ^^

Comment: How do you know it is not important? What else have you edited?

Comment: Not important in that context I mean the code is working my only problem is that when I convert my file variables from string to float I loose some data for an unknown reason.

Comment: @LokRidgmont Unfortunately newbies are really bad at knowing what is wrong with their code, and frequently leave out the code that actually contains the bug. It's better to post too much than too little.

Comment: This looks like a problem with your call to getline and using space as the delimiter. That won't work nicely with the newline character at the end of each line.

Comment: @NeilButterworth "*this can never work*" - actually, it can. [`ifstream::open()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open) accepts a `std::string` in C++11 and later

Comment: I didn't really omit anything important the only thing I left was my `numOfPoints` functions (which I'm sure is working fine but I'll add it anyway who knows). And I'm not really a "newbie" I worked for years using C# and I did this using C# with it working perfectly. But I don't understand how a simple `string` to `float` conversion can make me loose the first element of each line

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think the point was that the path is invalid.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat obviously, the OP was omitting the actual path for brevity, the actual path was not relevant to the issue of how to read the file after it has been opened

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm not saying I agree with NeilButterworth. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat since the path seem so important to you here it is: `C:\\Users\\My Name\\Desktop\\Computer Graphics\\File.acad`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code only accounts for space as a separator for your numbers but in fact you have space and newline as separators.

Change your inner loop to this, so it handles all whitespace

```
        string item;
        while (inFile >> item)
        {
            if (item == "END" || current_pos >= vc_size)
                break;

            x_coordinates[current_pos] = atof(item.c_str());

            current_pos++;
        }
```

Comment: Or, go back to using `getline()` to read each line like before, and use a `std::istringstream` on each iteration to parse the numbers from each line.

Comment: @john Doesn't `getline` act by its nature as a delimiter for new lines? What I find weird is that when I replace my `vector<float>` by a `vector<string>` and do  `my_coordinates[current_pos] = line` the code doesn't skip the first element of each line anymore. I therefor assumed that the problem would be in my conversion from `string` to `float`?

Comment: @LokRidgmont No, getline has newline as it's default delimiter but you changed that to space. Arguably it's poorly named, really it should be called get_to_delimiter, or something, see here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you for your answer and your help it's working now. Do you have any documentation for me to understand how `inFile >> item` acted as a delimiter for spaces and newlines?

Comment: @LokRidgmont Well it's quite technical, but see this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt Essentially `std::isspace` is called on each character read (along with the current locale) to test if the character counts as whitespace.